# AngularJS: Dynamic filtering through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to filter using dropdown and change value dynamically in `ng-repeat`, not sure how to do it, any hints?

Dropdown:

```
<label>Status</label>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="currentlySelected">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
</select>
```

Filter condition:

```
filter disable for All results
filter: {deleted_at : ''} --> Inactive results
filter: {deleted_at : null} --> Active results
```

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter : {status: currentlySelected}: true">
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Filter Based on Select Value";
   $scope.users = [
        {"id":18,"deleted_at" : ''},
        {"id":19,"deleted_at":'null'},
        {"id":21,"deleted_at":''},
        {"id":22,"deleted_at":''},
    ]
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body ng-controller="Main">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <label>Status</label>
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="currentlySelected">
      <option value="">All</option>
      <option value="null">Inactive</option>
      <option value="">Active</option>
   </select>

  <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter : {deleted_at: currentlySelected}: true">
    <h3>{{user.id}}</h3>
 </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need to put conditions for filter as I mentioned in question, like `| filter: {deleted_at : ''}` how should I do that?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: as there is no column as active or inactive in database Im filtering with `deleted_at` and `deleted_at == null`

Comment: what does those 2 mean inactive and active?

Comment: `filter: {deleted_at : ''} --> Inactive` and `filter: {deleted_at : null} --> Active` users

Comment: just change the value of the dropdown , check the demo

Comment: its filtering when I use filter without values from dropdown

Comment: what do you mean ? this is kinda spoon feeding

Comment: what happened? were you able to sort it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no trying to figure it out