# AngularJS: Pass Filter conditions dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to pass my filter conditions through dropdown menu to `ng-repeat`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="currentlySelected" ng-change="DropDownChnaged()">
    <option value ="">All</option>
    <option value="| filter : {deleted_at: null}">Active</option>
    <option value="| filter : {deleted_at: '!!'}">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

View

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users {currentlySelected}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.DropDownChnaged = function () {
    $scope.DropDownStatus = $scope.currentlySelected;
    alert(currentlySelected.DropDownChnaged);
};
```

When I pass set filter manually it works fine but when I try to pass dynamically its not working.

Comment: Is this another attempt to get an answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524210/angularjs-dynamic-filtering-through-ng-repeat)? Why not just write your own custom filter and be done with it?

Comment: If I would know how to do that, why would I ask question again?

Comment: Search this site for `angularjs custom filter`. [Here is one implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792039/angularjs-multiple-filter-with-custom-filter-function) that accepts multiple filter criteria. You could easily adopt it to your situation.

Comment: sure thnx.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already figured this out, but here is one way you could write a custom filter and then use it to filter your list of users. A custom filter should return a function that takes the collection as the first parameter and the filter criteria as the second parameter (you can add additional parameters if you would like to pass multiple filter criteria). This example uses the built-in `.forEach` of the collection you pass in. A check at the beginning ensures that both the collection and a filter criteria have been passed to the filter.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('userFilter', () => {
    return (userList, filter) => {
      if (!userList || !filter) {
        return userList;
      }
      var out = [];
      userList.forEach((user) => {
        if (filter === 'active') {
          if (user.deleted_at === null) {
            out.push(user);
          }
        } else {
          if (user.deleted_at !== null) {
            out.push(user);
          }
        }
      });
      return out;
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.users = [{
      name: 'John',
      deleted_at: null
    }, {
      name: 'Terry',
      deleted_at: '1/1/2018'
    }, {
      name: 'Joan',
      deleted_at: null
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="currentlySelected">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users | userFilter:currentlySelected">{{user.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
If you would rather put this in the controller it's slightly different because the filter method will get called for each item and expects a boolean result (`true` to include the item, `false` to exclude it). Here is how you would write the `$scope` method in your controller:

```
$scope.userFilter = (filter) => {
  return (user) => {
    if(!filter) return true;
    if (filter === 'active') {
      return user.deleted_at === null;
    } else {
      return user.deleted_at !== null;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how you would use it in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userFilter(currentlySelected)>{{user.name}}</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately still struggling with this issue, with your solution how can I put this custom filter as function in my existing controoler?

Comment: @JKLM I've updated the answer to show how to implement in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
`<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:currentlySelected>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value selected to the function called by ng-change.

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="currentlySelected" ng-change="DropDownChnaged(currentlySelected)">
             <option value ="">All</option>
             <option value="| filter : {deleted_at: null}">Active</option>
             <option value="| filter : {deleted_at: '!!'}">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.DropDownChnaged = function (value) {
        $scope.DropDownStatus = value;
        alert(currentlySelected.DropDownChnaged)
};
```

And then use 'DropDownStatus' value in the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users {DropDownStatus}">
```